# How to sort a list of tuples having mixed type elements in reverse order?

Tags: python-2.7, list, sorting

I have:

```
a = [(3.13, ['a', 'b', 'c']), (6.25, ['d', 'e', 'f']), (12.5, ['g', 'h', 'i'])]
```

but when I print out I get:

```
for i in a:
    print(i[0])
```

OUTPUT:

```
3.13
6.25
12.5
```

What I want to achive is the following:

OUTPUT:

```
12.5
6.25
3.13
```

I've tried :

```
for i in sorted(a, key = lambda x: x[0]):
    print(i[0])
```

but I got no effect on the output> I am trying to order my list of tuples.

Comment: `sorted(a, reverse=True)`.

Comment: So you want them sorted in *reverse* order, largest to smallest?

Comment: why did I get -1?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add `reverse=True` to reverse the sorting order:

```
a = [(3.13, ['a', 'b', 'c']), (6.25, ['d', 'e', 'f']), (12.5, ['g', 'h', 'i'])]

for i in sorted(a, key=lambda x: x[0], reverse=True):
    print(i[0])
```

> Output:
>
> ```
> 12.5
> 6.25
> 3.13
> ```

You could omit the `key` argument all together, since this is the default behavior, but in my opinion it's clearer to be explicit about what we're using as the sorting key.

Comment: there is no need for a `key`.

Comment: @hiroprotagonist Yeah it's the default behavior, but in my opinion it's clearer and more explicit this way.

Comment: so be it! (meaning: fine by me; +1).

Answer (score -1):

How about this?

```
a = [(3.13, ['a', 'b', 'c']), (6.25, ['d', 'e', 'f']), (12.5, ['g', 'h', 'i'])]
x = len(a) - 1
counter = 0
for i in a:
    y = x-counter
    print(a[y][0])
    counter +=1
```